# UIKIT Decoding HTML to String uses Times New Roman as font

Tags: html, swift, uikit

I have a text editor developed in UIKit and it saves the entries in html.
For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 24.0px '.AppleSystemUIFont'; color: #454545}
p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 17.0px '.AppleSystemUIFont'; color: #454545}
span.s1 {font-family: '.SFUI-Bold'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00px}
span.s2 {font-family: '.SFUI-RegularItalic'; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-size: 17.00px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Test</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span class="s2">Test</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user wants to see their entry again, the html gets decoded:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

I works, but for me the problem is, that somehow the decoder sets the font to be **Times New Roman**. I could simply set it back to **.systemFont** but I am also using .italicSystemFont and a bigger .systemFont as a headline. Is there an option to decode it with the right font?
Appreciate all help, thanks!

Comment: I also struggle with that. Seems there are a few questions around that topic https://openradar.appspot.com/6153065.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is that the html decoder has a bug so it replaces the saved **.systemFont** while decoding with Times New Roman. I could preserve that bug if I declared the font with a name. For example:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "identifier", size: 17.0)
```

When I used the identifier of the system font (which normally isn't a good practice), this bug was resolved.